# Why I can't install firebase in angular 2?

Tags: angular, firebase

I try to install Firebase in Angular 2 with the following commands:
`npm install angularfire2 firebase --save` or `npm install git+https://github.com/angular/angularfire2.git`

But,not working. I get the error:

```
├── angularfire2@2.0.0-beta.7 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bootstrap@~3.3.x
├── firebase@3.6.8 
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @angular/core@2.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/http@2.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-jwt@0.1.25 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
```

My versions of angular-cli, npm, node and OS are:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.19-3
npm: 3.10.8
node: 7.0.0
os: linux x64
```

What is the problem? Do I need to upgrade my angular-cli version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to install/update  bootstrap and rxjs.

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY bootstrap@~3.3.x

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12